# Simultaneously run two methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a text-based adventure game. My code is something like this:

```
class NPC(object):
    def __init__(self, health, damage, rate_of_fire):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        def attack(self, opponent):
            def attackopponent():
                while self.health > 0 and opponent.health > 0:
                    opponent.health -= self.weapon.damage
                    sleep(self.rate_of_fire)
            def opponentattack():
                while self.health > 0 and opponent.health > 0:
                    self.health -= opponent.weapon.damage
                    sleep(opponent.rate_of_fire)
```

I've researched this for a week and all the answers either don't work or I'm too new to understand them. Can somebody explain to me how I can simultaneously run these two methods?

I want each NPC to have their own rate of fire and own damage, and shoot each other until one of them dies.

Comment: Well, what do you want it to do? You should describe the expected behaviour.

Comment: Fix your indentation. I see only one method here, `__init__`, and something that *might* be a method if it were indented correctly: `attack`. However, `attack` seems to define two functions and does nothing with them.

Comment: `attackopponent` and `opponentattack` shouldn't use `while` and `sleep` - it has to be in `mainloop` function

Comment: "simultaneously" would require highly advanced techniques like threading. I don't think you are asking the proper question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem this may help you in figuring out what you actually want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know it does nothing- I need to know how to run them at the same time and that's why I'm posting this.

Comment: Run *what*. Your code's indentation is clearly off, I can't know what you are referring to. There is exactly 1 method in your code.

Comment: I think your ambition is bigger than your understanding of programming. Go through more tutorials.

Comment: What most of us are getting at, is that you most likely don't need to run anything simultaneously (9 times out of 10 "simultaneous" is an illusion of things happening really close to each other) If you edit your code so it has some sort of flow, we can tell how to use your function, and what your desired results are, then we can probably give you help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: in most versions of Python, you cannot.  You can multi-thread for some reasons in Python (running C code modules), but C python has a Global Interpretr Lock (GIL) and this prevents multi-threading any python functions.

Likely, the "real" answer here is that you want to decide on the granularity of your world and then queue up functions to run at that granularity ... s.t. your two functions would be "simultaneous" if they both ran in the same "tick" ... but this is way beyond a simple stack exchange answer.

Look at how turn based gameplay works --- say XCOM (or XCOM2) or Neverwinter Nights 2.  A realtime example (and, bonus points, in python) is eve-online (which is now free-to-play).  You can't look inside at the code, but if you play for awhile, you'll get the idea that there's only one operation per second per entity in eve ... so anything that happens in the same "second" is, in game terms, simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is more complex than this primitive example.

Normally game has `mainloop` which executes functions which make only small "step". Because every function makes only small "step" in the same loop so finally it looks like all functions work simultaneously.

```
class NPC(object):

    def __init__(self, health, damage, rate_of_fire):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

    def attack(self, opponent):
        while self.health > 0 and opponent.health > 0:
             attackopponent(opponent)
             opponentattack(opponent)
             sleep(self.rate_of_fire)

    def attackopponent(opponent):
        if self.health > 0 and opponent.health > 0:
            opponent.health -= self.weapon.damage

    def opponentattack(opponent):
        if self.health > 0 and opponent.health > 0:
            self.health -= opponent.weapon.damage
```